# AttributeError: module 'gensim.models.word2vec' has no attribute 'load'

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I import a text file from the desktop to do with gensim model on jupyter notebook. However, it return that:

> "AttributeError  Traceback (most recent call last)
>    in 
>   ----> 1 model = word2vec.load(r'C:\Users\qlm\Desktop\globalwarming.txt')
>
> AttributeError: module 'gensim.models.word2vec' has no attribute
>   'load'"

How can I fix this problem

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import gensim
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from gensim.models import word2vec
from collections import defaultdict
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

model = word2vec.Text8Corpus(r'C:\Users\qlm\Desktop\globalwarming.txt')
model = word2vec.load(r'C:\Users\qlm\Desktop\globalwarming.txt')
```

Comment: Please update your question so code and traceback are properly formatted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a module named `word2vec` and inside it a class named `Word2Vec`, since the `Word2Vec` class is imported in [`__init__.py` of `gensim.models`](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/develop/gensim/models/__init__.py#L14) you can import it as you tried before:

```
from gensim.models import Word2Vec
```

Then you'll have access to the [load method](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/develop/gensim/models/word2vec.py#L1310).

You can also use the full namespace too.

So:

```
# Will work as long as models.__init__ keep it available
from gensim.models import Word2Vec
```

But:

```
# Will always work as long as the namespace is not altered
from gensim.models.word2vec import Word2Vec
```

I personally prefer the second choice.