# AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'Vocab' on <module 'gensim.models.word2vec'

Tags: python-3.x, error-handling, gensim, attribution

My problem is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55577628/attributeerror-module-gensim-models-word2vec-has-no-attribute-load) question. I tried both solutions posted on the question, but I still receive the error that the attribute "Vocab" is not available in the gensim.models.word2vec module.

The part of my code using this attribute is here

```
# if word in model.keys(): #use model.vocab for w2v model and model.keys() for Glove dicts
        if word in self.w2v_model.wv.vocab:
            vector = self.w2v_model.wv[word]
        else:
            vector = [0] * 100
```

Answer (score 2):

`pip install gensim==3.8.1` worked - the issue was with a particular Gensim package version.

Answer (score 0):

Gensim 4.0.0, with many fixes & performance improvements, has also changed some property/method names for simplicity & long-term consistency. A project wiki page has a guide to adapting older code to match the new APIs:

https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/wiki/Migrating-from-Gensim-3.x-to-4

But, your code doesn't need to use `.vocab` at all. The set of word-vectors, `w2v_model.wv`, can answer whether a key is `in` itself already. So the following code should work both pre-4.0 and in 4.0-and-above:

```py
    if word in self.w2v_model.wv:
        vector = self.w2v_model.wv[word]
    else:
        vector = [0] * 100
```

(Separately, if you did choose to keep using an older Gensim to put-off any other code changes, it's be better to use `3.8.3`, the last in the `3.x` series, released May 2020, rather than an older/buggier `3.8.1`, released in September 2019. But some key word2vec-related operations will be faster and use less memory in `gensim-4.0.0` & higher, so rolling-back should be avoided if possible.)